# I can't get JavaScript working, is their an alternative for using id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I will be using expand/collapse container several times on the page, and I want to avoid using id. It worked just fine when I've had only one container, but as I'm adding more it is not working. I want to be able to expand/collapse each container individually.

```js
function switchVisible() {
  if (document.getElementById('div1')) {
    if (document.getElementById('div1').style.display == 'none') {
      document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
}
$("#show_less").click(function() {
  if (this.value == "Show More") this.value = "Show Less";
  else this.value = "Show More";
});
```

```css
#div2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <p>This is div 1</p>
</div>
<div id="div2">
  <p>This is div 2</p>
</div>
<input id="show_less" type="button" value="Show More" onclick="switchVisible();" />
<div id="div1">
  <p>This is div 1</p>
</div>
<div id="div2">
  <p>This is div 2
    <br />
  </p>
</div>
<input id="show_less" type="button" value="Show More" onclick="switchVisible();" />
```

Comment: "but document.getElementsByClassName method did not work for me": why don't you show us that code too as it's possible you were using it incorrectly; it returns a nodelist, not one single element.

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to obtain. When to show and when to hide content, under wich condition, in response of wich events. You probably need to simply wrap "groups" in containers, but it's hard to say without understanding exaclty your needs

Comment: Multiple ``div`` can't have same id it violate W3 Standers if you want to use same style or same JS functions on elements try to add ``class`` to them rather than ``id``

Comment: since you are using jquery why not use it's selector (and show/hide/toggle) function instead of the DOM methods?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/webIra7/44Lgfwjd/

Answer (score 1):

I did it using class! When you use getElementsByClassName, it return a list of elements, not only a single element, that means you need to tell wich one you want in the list.

You can see [a working exemple here!](https://jsfiddle.net/uzwqp6nt/1/)

I added class to your div, keeping the same name as your id.

In my exemple, I added two parameters to your function: index and input

The index is to tell wich group we want to show/hide, the input is to change the value of the input "Show More/Less" directly into this function as well, instead of adding an event.

Also, I used variable to make it more clean!

Here is the Javascript:

```
function switchVisible(index, input) {
    var div1 = document.getElementsByClassName('div1')[index];
    var div2 = document.getElementsByClassName('div2')[index];
    if (div1) {
        if (div1.style.display == 'none') {
            div1.style.display = 'block';
            div2.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            div1.style.display = 'none';
            div2.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }

    if (input.value == "Show More") input.value = "Show Less";
    else input.value = "Show More";

}
```

And the HTML

```
<div class="div1">
    <p>This is div 1</p>
</div>
<div class="div2">
    <p>This is div 2</p>
</div>
<input id="show_less" type="button" value="Show More" onclick="switchVisible(0, this);" />
<div class="div1">
    <p>This is div 1</p>
</div>
<div class="div2">
    <p>This is div 2
        <br />
    </p>
</div>
<input id="show_less" type="button" value="Show More" onclick="switchVisible(1, this);" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, your answer was the most helpful out of all.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery .click is going to handle the event every time. You don't need to assign a function to the onclick of the button as well. Just move all of your code into the .click event like this:

```
$("#show_less").click(function(){
 if (document.getElementById('div1')) {
     if (document.getElementById('div1').style.display == 'none') {
         document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';
         document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'none';
     }
     else {
         document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'block';
     }
 }
 if (this.value=="Show More") this.value = "Show Less";
 else this.value = "Show More";
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I'm trying to avoid using id. I can not use the same id on the web page, W3C will generate an error. Is their any other alternative method?

Answer (score 0):

*edited response*

It isn't working appropriately because when you do any sort of "Get Element By Class Name" the first element matching that class name found in the DOM is returned. That's why the first "Div1" is toggling instead of the second "Div1" element. You could handle this in a few different ways (there is always a way to make it work); however, I stand by the convention of using an explicit ID for each element you wish to manipulate or interact with. Even if these elements are generated via code, you should still be able to programmatically assign them unique IDs. Otherwise, you'll need to write some roundabout script that identifies the calling element (or its parent div) then performs the necessary manipulation (as illustrated by @Shryme's response).

Comment: I've tried using class as an alternative and it didn't work. Here is a code https://jsfiddle.net/webIra7/44Lgfwjd/

Comment: Instead of mixing and matching jQuery with javascript have you tried the jQuery class selector instead of document.getElementsByClassName ?

An example would be:

$('.Div1').hide();

or 

$('.Div1).show();

Comment: When you do any sort of "Get Element By Class Name" the first occurrence of that class name found in the DOM will be returned. Therefore, you should use something more explicit, such as an ID. Why can't you just assign unique element IDs to each div you wish to toggle?